# Maven web project excluding *.java files

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am creating  a web project through maven command line and then converting that into an eclipse project. But in the eclipse project all java files are getting excluded by default. I have to manually remove the exclusion in order for the project to run.

Can you help me find, if I can change some maven setting in order to stop this incident?

Create maven project command

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.pkg1 -DartifactId=AtmosphereTest -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp -DinteractiveMode=false
```

Clean command

```
mvn clean install -X
```

Create eclipse project command

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

The exclusion of java in eclipse project
![The exclusion of java in eclipse project][2]

[image]

Comment: Excuse me, but its the resources folder. If there are java source files in there, you're doing something very wrong. Java source files go in src/main/java according to maven conventions.

Comment: src\main\resource is the default source folder being setup by maven. I was also hoping to see something like 'src\main\java' as the source folder but it is not. Maybe there are some maven configuration that I need to manipulate. I am not sure what and how

Comment: Do you use the m2e eclipse plugin?

Comment: no, I am using the mvn through command line

Comment: Is this perhaps a Maven parent project and not a module? Is there not a separate war module where the missing directories do exist? I can't imagine that the maven-archetype-webapp archetype generates a broken project.

Comment: I have updated the question with a structure of the project created by maven.

Comment: I would suggest you leave the `mvn eclipse:eclipse` aside and use the m2e plugin of Eclipse. It will correctly setup source paths. @Gimby is right, src/main/java is the default source folder. It seems not to be included in the archetype, so you have to create the folder yourself.

Comment: Weird though, according to the archetype it is correct apparently since it really does not generate the directory. That's not how I've been brought up however, and neither is the mvn eclipse:eclipse project generator apparently. Agreed: use m2eclipse to not only generate the project but also to have it keeping it up to date too as you change the poms. This way of working seems really outdated.

Comment: m2e is something I usually use. This was just for a "Hello World". Thanks guys for your inputs. Do you suggest I raise a bug for this?